# Why does the CKFetchRecordsOperation not work?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

This operation does not retrieve anything. The CkFetchRecordsCOmpletion block does not get called? Thanks for your time!

```
public func getRecord(recordID: CKRecord.ID, completion: @escaping (CKRecord?, CKError?) -> Void) {
    let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [recordID])
    operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (records, error) in
        // Checking for potential errors
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error as? CKError)
            print(error)
        }

        if let record = records?[recordID] {
            completion(record, nil)
        }
    }

    operation.qualityOfService = .utility
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer(identifier: "something").privateCloudDatabase
    privateDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

Comment: I copied your code into my app (and changed the database to my own) and the code worked perfectly. You have some error not related directly to the code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then I will try again and see how it works!